# Calling docker containers from C++ project

Tags: c++, ipc

I have a project in c++ and several dockers in local.Is there any way I can give my parameters from c++ to these dockers and return output of these dockers for specific applications inside them ?

Comment: This question is too vague to help you with. What interfaces do those containers expose? Are they listening on a network socket? UNIX socket? Are you in a position to `docker run` them and pass input via stdin/stdout?

Comment: I am not using socket currently, I am in a position to [docker run] or [docker exec]  them and pass input as you said.

Comment: Then your problem is reduced to "how do I interact with the stdin/stdout of an external child process in C++", which has tons of pre-existing questions on this site.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard inter-process communication in C++. One way for processes to communicate is through sockets. This is a very common choice with containers. C++ has no standard API for sockets. Docker containers run in Linux, so you can use the POSIX socket API.